# What is the meaning of the preposition "back" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

> We learned how to test-drive the repository **back** in Section x.x, Creating and Reading Records, on page xxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Back* is not a preposition here, it is an adverb. It means at a previous time, as JSBangs said.

Comment: Thanks for your answering! I am really confused about the structure of the sentence, now I get it clear!

Answer (score 3):

This is a colloquial way of saying, *We learned how to test-drive the repository **in the previous section** x.x, Creating and Reading Records.*